# fetchしたremoteブランチのトラッキングブランチがcheckout時に自動で生成されない

Tags: git

昔は

```
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
```

だけで、fetchしたremote branchのトラッキングブランチを自動で生成した上でそのトラッキングブランチにチェックアウトできていたと思うのですが、今では出来なくなっていて、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
error: pathspec 'BRANCH_NAME' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

そのため現状では、

```
git checkout -b BRANCH_NAME origin/BRANCH_NAME
```

としているのですが、より簡単な方法があれば教えて下さい
version2.6で`git checkout BRANCH_NAME`で問題ない方もいらっしゃる様なので、gitのバージョンの問題ではないようです。

Comment: ご質問の内容変更について了解しました。一旦、回答を削除します。何か判りましたら別回答を投稿します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。バージョン依存しないことだけ追記しておきました。

Comment: 手元では2.5.1を使っていますが、ずっと `git checkout hoge` でトラッキングブランチを作成できています。ブランチ名をtypoしてる、なんてことはないですよね。 / `git checkout hoge` で十分なのであれば、タイトルも「簡単に作成する方法」ではなく、これができなくなったのは何故？ということが伝わる文にした方が関心を持ってもらえるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: あとは複数のremoteに同名のブランチが存在する場合も、pathspec ... did not match ... が表示されるようです。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございました。ご指摘の通り複数のremoteが存在するのが問題だったようです。今は使っていないremoteを削除することで、`git checokut hoge`でトラッキングブランチが生成されるようになりました。回答として投稿していただければそのままベストアンサーとさせていただきます。

Comment: @shirakia ユーザ名に@を付けてコメントするとそのユーザに通知が行くので@を付けた方が良いですよ。(逆に付けないとトラッキングしきれないです)

Comment: @unarist お手数ですが回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Comment: @kotatsu ありがとうございます。今後そうするようにします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Git 1.6.6](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.6.txt) 以降現在に至るまで、 `git checkout <branch>` でトラッキングブランチを作成できます。

ただし、指定した名前のブランチが複数の remote に存在するとエラーになります。

> If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch **in exactly one remote** (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```
>
> <sub>--- https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html より引用。強調は私によるものです。</sub>

この場合のエラーメッセージは、存在しないブランチ名を指定したときと同様のものです。

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/some-branch
  remotes/hoge/some-branch
  remotes/hoge/some-branch

$ git checkout some-branch
error: pathspec 'some-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決しました。エラーメッセージがもうちょっと分かりやすいとよかったですね。