# call dein#update()の際、[dein] error: pathspec 'ref' did not match any file(s) known to git. が出力される

Tags: vim

`call dein#update()`よりプラグインのアップデートを行った際、
`[dein] error: pathspec 'ref' did not match any file(s) known to git.`が出力されます。
解決法をご存知の方ご助言を宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これと同じ話でしょう。
revision 指定をしていますね？ dein が ref というブランチをチェックアウトしようとしたのだと思います。
[fetchしたremoteブランチのトラッキングブランチがcheckout時に自動で生成されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18047/fetch%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fremote%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%81%AE%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%81%8Ccheckout%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E3%81%A7%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)